# Javascript Working in IE8 comp mode but not standards mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a JS script that works on IE8 compatibility mode, FF, Chrome, Opera, but not IE8 standards mode.

As I think standards mode is more strict than compatibility mode, maybe there's something wrong with my code. How can I debug? Is there something that shows me things that would work in compatibility mode but standard?

Also, in the short term, how can I change the user browser to use compatibility mode in JS. I don't want to change the entire site (ie, change the template doctype), how do I do it in JS?

Thanks.

Comment: In IE, press F12 and look at the console tab. Then do whatever it is that isn't working, you'll most likely see a javascript error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For forcing compatibility mode, you need a custom header. See this link http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx

If you post the Javascript that is not working, may be we can point out the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't consider forcing compatibility mode anything other than a quick fix, though. There are lots of improvements in the IE8 engine that are lost by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the value of the `document.documentMode` value in JavaScript. If your page is in quirks mode, it goes back to IE 5 behavior, which can mess up your code.

To check the document mode, use this little piece of JavaScript.

```
var docMode = document.documentMode;
if (!docMode|| docMode < 8) {
    // Old IE or IE8 or later compatibility mode.
    // 5 for quirks mode, 7 for compatibility mode,
    // undefined for IE7 or earlier.
} else {
    // IE8 or later standards mode.
}
```

It's hard to tell what your problem is if you don't post code though. Maybe we can figure it out if you show us what code behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

When the controls are define by "name" not by "id", the compatible mode work and standard mode not work, I solve my problem by inserting "id".

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having was likely a css-related jquery issue.  I noticed that only in ie8 Standards Mode my tables were not resizing properly and after debugging noticed that my css for the table had a duplicate entry.  There must be a difference in the way that jquery..css("border-left-width") responds in ie8 as the following css renders correctly in ie7 and ie9 Standards Modes, but not in ie8 Standard Mode:

```
table {
 border: 8px solid #C2DDEE;
 border: none;
}
```